# Calculating time it takes savings to double in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to write a script for calculating the length of time it takes an input to double on 5% APR

here is what I have, I am just getting the incorrect answer. Is it a math or code issue? Any help appreciated.

```
i = float(input("What is your principal amount"))
r = float(.05)
year = 0
while i < (i * 2):
  ie = (i * r)
  i = i + ie
  year += 1
  continue
else:
  print("The number of years it takes for your sum to double is", year)
```

Comment: I don't know much about finance, but I'm pretty sure there's a faster & easier way to do this with math and exponents.

Comment: You're comparing `i` to `i * 2` -- the program doesn't know that you want to compare your *new* value of `i` to an *old* value for `i * 2` unless you make a copy of that value.

Comment: how do I do that sorry very  new to this?

Comment: I'm surprised you get any answer at all.  When do you expect `i < (i * 2)` to be false and the loop to end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you tell the loop to stop when `i` is greater than `i*2`, however, every time the loop runs `i*2` is recalculated. To fix this, you should make a variable to store the end number, then compare it to that. Like this:

```
i = float(input("What is your principal amount"))
r = float(.05)
year = 0
doubled = i * 2
while i < doubled:
  ie = (i * r)
  i = i + ie
  year += 1
  continue
else:
  print("The number of years it takes for your sum to double is", year)
```

If you use `i < i*2`, then when `i` is 1 the statement will be read as `1 < 2`. When `i` is 2, the statement will be read as `2 < 4`. When `i` is 3, the statement will be read as `2 < 6`. And so on... The loop will only end when the numbers get so large that Python just crashes.

On the other hand, if you use a variable, like `doubled = i*2`, then `i*2` will only be evaluated once.

**However, in the real world you should always prefer math to loops.** I understand that this is a homework assignment, but future visitors to this question should unconditionally use the formula instead. This is the code that uses the formula:

```
from math import log

apr = 0.05  # as a decimal
doublingTime = log(2) / log(1 + apr)
print(doublingTime)
```

Comment: we are supposed to do it in a longer way I am pretty sure because we are practicing loops. I am just confused what I did wrong

Comment: @PieCharmer Oh sorry. I've updated my answer with the correct solution to your problem (it was just a simple mistake). In the future, if you ask a question on homework, then you should specify so that answerers know not to fix it *too* much :)

Comment: thanks Michael, I am glad to know how close I was I thought I was missing that I was just putting it in the wrong place, cheers